# typescript multiple keyof in operators in single object type

Tags: typescript

all explanations on the comments below

```js
/**
 * two requirements:
 *  1. keys in PS must be in parseProps
 *  2. keys exist in P is allowed to be in parseProps, but not required
 *  3. PS is a subset of P.
 */

type Test<P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}> = {

    parseProps?: {
        // satisfies requirement 1
        [key in keyof P]?: (prop: P[key]) => PS[key];

        // satisfies requirement 2
        [key in keyof PS]: (prop: any) => PS[key]; //syntax error -  only one of these [...]:(...) allowed in object type
    };
}
```

how to satisfy both requirements on a single object type?

### what I expect:

```js
export const createTest = <P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}>(
    test: Test<P, PS>
): Test<P, PS> => {
    return test;
};


const test = createTest<{ type1: any, type2: any, }, { type1: any }>({
    parseProps: {
        type1: (prop: any) => prop,
        type2: (prop: any) => prop, //should be error: type2 does not exists in PS
        type3: (prop: any) => prop, //should be error: type3 does not exists in P: error as expected
    }
})
```

### working examples for both separately:

```js
/**
 * satisfy requirement 1 example
 */
type Test1<P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}> = {
    parseProps?: {
        // satisfies requirement 1
        [key in keyof P]?: (prop: P[key]) => PS[key];
    };
}

export const createTest1 = <P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}>(
    test: Test1<P, PS>
): Test1<P, PS> => {
    return test;
};


const test1 = createTest1<{ type1: any, type2: any, },{type1: any}>({
    parseProps: {
        type1: (prop: any) => prop,
        type2: (prop: any) => prop,
        type3: (prop: any) => prop, //type3 does not exists in P: error as expected
    }
})

/**
 * satisfy requirement 2 example
 */
type Test2<P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}> = {
    parseProps?: {
        // satisfies requirement 2
        [key in keyof PS]: (prop: any) => PS[key]; //syntax error -  only one of these [...]:(...) allowed in object type
    };
}

export const createTest2 = <P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}>(
    test: Test2<P, PS>
): Test2<P, PS> => {
    return test;
};


const test2 = createTest2<{ type1: any, type2: any, },{type1: any}>({
    parseProps: {
        type1: (prop: any) => prop,
        type2: (prop: any) => prop, //type2 does not exists in PS: error as expected
        type3: (prop: any) => prop,
    }
})
```

### Playground

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgXA7ge2gJwKYEcCuBLTAWwwDt4AuKWaaARgDpoBrDATwGdo8ToAFAZWiEc7eNABGGLj15U40AEyMWHaBgAeeUZ259Bw0RKm6ADgEM07DLzTIT7OcChR4rE1IAqGUQB5ea9XhSABNOMxJWABoqGj0AoJJQ6ABvaABtFWlmNmQAMz4AXQB+cmhw1mgAX2gAXhTKgD5alOcYWPNLa1t7Epa22NjgYGh2M3gtXLxvdGx8IlIxWhiBmgy2LJU8wt6AChNu0t411gKASlqmgWOCgG5WlcHh0fH2SenMXAIMYjJFZZXjhscvkBAVSnsDmUIucapd+NcbtAhuxWGQzOo1GhbGhoABaGjIEgAGwqhKkW3gAAtvFI0vR6WCdvT6OczESichEBhgllkOIAFYYADGYlc7n+lTukEqUCG0EpnIQqGeEwq4mQVKKrVAEBg8kQlLGXAC7hFjigGhMyDQYiFhMMQswYwwXkMdT88RCYQi0X6cQ0CSSqUBuk2IOKpXKVWayUaO3+QVEpVd8D8kT0DSgp2T3lTvHTAiasL6A0w8BwaB4ifgUslrSgdpIhmrzUdGGdKZ8qTFGFokZ9CDcGAU-aiVXT3aHfahFTjyX+HSsNjs7FK879Ax704hdlHMKa+zsvoeNB7I+gO5Me4u0EPJnTyIVOCJPMkmOxpTP0GCyGmJA1ARaPAOgyPw-ybkOADM4J3texZ3g+wDsE+L5GO+1qflB36-pw-5iBoQEgXwpQYFi1plJwlrCkEwQSlAlSnPWkA6nIIxjKqMyfPMvy0AEZiECYRIYOakA9tAKa0B6AZejOx6xAInqJJwwaZKGwLbKO0Z1LGRYlu0FhLt07C9OuJ5Ik87GvFMnAfHM3wLHQ4GxCGPBhhpF6wXw1z7noCISrWrSWtatr2raTpBBJzRSYEMnlHJNAKdJSkpOkqmuepvARjOWn1A08Z+tWOaiJJ+YZlmRXwCVBb8EWTSmbEZYVlWua1lKrSNs2ua8XUbYdl1XaDu405xYNw6jumlQTqNw0RFUeX1TQi5dCua5OaeU4wZC5Q+Qha2jeel5wQe3TxSsPbQR5W3QjeCHmed2F-gBBHaFkvAkWROJmJR6imjRdHSoxkCymArEqq8FS2V8PxiAofECUJIliSmCjRYG3pRP8iUxclKnrGprBbJlvRRtU2mNDGC4GctPSrRujxsS8bw2bMUMOQoe0udkBMgvwYKXbuM4+VcKi3OZKJohipHYniBLEqSJDkvkVI0ukzKMsyrLspy3K8gK1Gjf59GBT9wXQB1YXthFuaw+6-hJUkcWY4I9vKalePpdz7kkzGcYJrmFUo6VhbleJ1tphmN4LTM5aVggLX0W1QOQObceiDbZvhS6YeTkN437Xnk0pVumlzpTnTLvYtNmcX-NXoLN0nXtZ6bQL20N0ed1DrDP6PfhmgvboAjvdLX0mtR3JN1BLd1238GN36MoA1AQA)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need intersection of mapped types https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgXA7ge2gJwKYEcCuBLTAWwwDt4AuKWaaARgDpoBrDATwGdo8ToAFAZWiEc7eNABGGLj15U40AEyMWHaBgAeeUZ259Bw0RKm6ADgEM07DLzTIT7OcChR4rE1IAqGUQB5ea9XhSABNOMxJWABoqGj0AoJJQ6ABvaABtFWlmNmQAMz4AXQB+cmhw1mgAX2gAXhTKgD5alOcYWPNLa1t7Epa22NjgYGh2M3gtXLxvdGx8IlIxWhiBmgy2LJU8wt6AChNu0t411gKASlqmgWOCgG5lqugAMj6VweHR8fZJ6cxcAgxiGRFPcBscNjl8gICqU9gcyhFzjVLvxrnd+lU0ZUgA

Comment: @AlekseyL. tried, does not work

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve. `PS` keys are a subset of `P` keys, right? And if you want to allow only `PS` keys in `parseProps`, then why do you need `[key in keyof P]?` ?

Comment: yes, but if you try to add a prop to PS that does not exist in P, it won't be error over PS, so my alternative is to restrict `parseProps` to allow only what exists in P and require what exists in PS @AlekseyL.